# SQL - remove multiple entries by a non-unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query where I have multiple results from with a non-unique id that I want to get rid of based on if one entry equals a value.

ie. `id, billID, transaction` - there can be multiple entries for a `billID` with different `transaction` values. I want to find `transaction` values that equal `'testValue'` and then remove all entries with that `billID`.

So far I got my original data that I put into a `#tmp1`. Then I'm placing all `billID`'s where `Transaction = 'testValue'` into `#tmp2`.

How do I join these two together, to give results of `#tmp1` where not equal to the `billID` in #`tmp2`?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: sample data: 1, 20, 'testValue';  2, 20, 'text'; 3, 21, 'text';  result: 3, 21, 'text'

Comment: Please do not put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely** hard to read it.... Instead: update your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a single query:

```
delete from t
where t.billid in (select billid from t where transaction = 'TestValue')
```